# applying StringFormat to DateTime column of WPF 4.0 DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I need to apply a StringFormat to DateTime Column of a DataGrid (WPF4.0) at run time. I have used the column template to create a column of a data grid. The value of format is set at run time by applying setting in the application.

Any one knows that how we can apply StringFormat to DateTime Colum(Column Template) at run time.

I am waiting for positive response from side.

Thanks & Regards,
Deepak